# Как вызвать SOAP метод Xamarin

Tags: java, soap, xamarin

Как правильно вызвать метод из веб-сервиса в *Xamarin* под *андроид*?

Интерфейс

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface UserWebService {
    @WebMethod
    boolean getAuth(String name, String pass);
}
```

Реализация

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.websystique.springmvc.webservice.UserWebService")
public class UserWebServiceImpl implements UserWebService{

    @Override
    public boolean getAuth(String name, String pass) {
        if (name.equals(pass)) 
        { 
            return true;
            }
        else 
        {
            return false; 
            } 
        }
    }
```

И паблишер

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.webservice;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class UserWebServicePublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Endpoint.publish( "http://localhost:9000/ws/auth", new UserWebServiceImpl()); 
    }

}
```